# Calling React native method which should return data(string for Instance) to android activity on android button click

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have an android app on which I have a Button.On click of this button I need to invoke a method in react-native and after some computation on react-native server, I need to get the result like a string on my Textview.
I am new to react-native and timelines are less so need to know how this can be achieved.
Till now I am able to run a helloworld sample react-native demo project on android.
I think there could be something related to callbacks, emitting events
or promise.But don't know exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Native Modules iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) and [Native Modules Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html).

It has everything you want.

For iOS there is one more reference [Communication between native and React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html)

I think it has more than enough documentation, go through it and you will get success.

Check [Link1](https://www.promptworks.com/blog/writing-native-modules-for-react-native) , [Link2](http://blog.tylerbuchea.com/how-to-create-a-react-native-ios-native-module/) and [Link3](https://hashnode.com/post/building-custom-android-modules-for-react-native-ciqcba1hj00phaj53f9u4laww) also.